# Is it OK to waste a little food for the sake of etiquette?

Tags: food

If a host offers you a drink and you are the guest, you leave a little drink at bottom of the glass as etiquette. Is this considered wasting food  ? Is it a sin  ?

Comment: This so called "etiquette" is wrong and a bad manner. And certainly in conflict with the teaching of Islam.

Answer (score 1):

Wasting itself is haram even if its a little bit or not, its because there is people that cant afford to buy or got the same luck as us (Alhamdulillah) to have Food, water and many other things.
I'm sorry if I said something wrong but this is what I think about this subject. This is how we do it in our family we dont waste food at all

Comment: I think that you are right in not wasting *usable* food and drink. But what is left in another ones glass or on another ones plate cannot be safely donated, out of medical reasons for possible infections. It is different within the family.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've ever come across this as etiquette. What's your source?

Generally, the idea of a party is to be social and gregarious and not to eat and drink all at once. Hence drinking slowly is etiquette and this is why it's likely that at the end of a party food and drink is left as everyone is following this rule of decorum apart from the odd guest who doesn't know how to behave.

It is haram to waste food and drink, though. And one would expect the host to donate the food and drink to a charity ...

Comment: I have heard (citation needed) of cultures, where it is requested to eat all, to signal it tasted good, and other cultures where is is expected to leave some traces of food on the plate, to signal it was plenty.